# Communicating with ROS application from Xojo

Tags: ros-lunar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

I'm going to be running ros on a sbc x86 based, with a Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit OS. I will be writing a GUI application in Xojo
and I'm going to need to be able to read information from the ros program.

Is there any information out there on making your own subscriber in C or python? Anybody been down this road yet?

I'll still look around on the internet a bit more, but if anybody has a code snip-it or two, that would very useful for me.

Thanks for any help you can provide,

Robert

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294960/communicating-with-ros-application-from-xojo/) by [Robert_d1968](https://answers.ros.org/users/35822/robert_d1968/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is there any information out there on making your own subscriber in C or python?

C is not supported (or at least not without writing some wrappers yourself), but Python is fully supported. Do the [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber) not cover this?

---

Edit: unless with "own subscriber" you mean "without using the standard ROS client libraries". That would be something else.

---

Edit2:

> No, I wont be using ROS client libraries for this GUI. I will need to learn how to do this and somewhat quick too.

Writing your own client lib is not going to be trivial. Doable, but not trivial.

You could perhaps take a look at [rosbridge_suite](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite). It's a JSON bridge for ROS1. Anything that supports web- or a tcp socket and JSON should be integrable that way.

There are various implementations of client libs for the `rosbridge` protocol. See [roslibpy](http://roslibpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for one example. None of those need a full ROS installation.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robert_d1968](https://answers.ros.org/users/35822/robert_d1968/) on 2018-06-22**:
No, I wont be using ROS client libraries for this GUI. I will need to learn how to do this and somewhat quick too.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-06-22**:
The client libraries (C++ and Python) do a pretty good job of working as libraries, particularly the python client library. What prevents you from using it within your application?

**Comment by [Robert_d1968](https://answers.ros.org/users/35822/robert_d1968/) on 2018-06-22**:
Xojo is a Basic language IDE that said, I don't think it would be able to use them in that IDE. But since ROS supports pascal, I may try out PYQT for the GUI, that should mean a lot less hassle for me.

**Comment by [Robert_d1968](https://answers.ros.org/users/35822/robert_d1968/) on 2018-06-22**:
Thanks for the tip with the ROS bridge! Xojo also supports JSON. This should be a breeze with the bridge.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-22**:
You might want to take a look at the Python lib I linked to.

Also: [robotwebtools.org](http://robotwebtools.org).

**Comment by [Robert_d1968](https://answers.ros.org/users/35822/robert_d1968/) on 2018-06-22**:
Thank you, I did look at that library you linked, a lot of great information there! looks like  I have a lot of reading to do.  :)